How do you prove you are Jewish?
I have never been asked to prove I am Jewish, but I often wondered how I could do it.  My mother was born in Cairo and her mother in Damascus, and good luck in retrieving archives from hostile regimes (assuming they haven't been destroyed already).  However, I brought two documents with me from Egypt: (1) A 1967 certificate saying I haven't been married before, signed by the Chief Rabbi of Egypt, and (2) My birth certificate, released by Egyptian authorities, which states also that I am Jewish.  Would either or both be proof enough?
(Were Holocaust survivors emigrating to Israel asked to prove in writing they were Jewish?)

Two witnesses can establish anything

I had two specific unanswered questions, and a parenthetical third.

Were this question reopened, the edit you added would make no sense since it lacks any context. Even with a link it doesn't do anything to explain what is different/unique about this question that isn't covered there. Take [edit] opportunities to reevaluate the whole post together and improve it. "Edit, not append" is usually a good rule.

@MauriceMizrahi when I was trying to get a visa for Israel they asked me to prove my Jewishness. I submitted my grandparents ketubbah from Cairo (also signed by Chief Rabbi!), their refugee paperwork from France for being Jewish, and my mother's and then my birth certificate. Israel wouldn't accept these documents and told me to go to a Rabbi to get a letter. I took these same documents to my Rabbi who gave me a letter.
